# can`t escape backslash and ] symbol in jQuery form validation plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I`m using jQuery form validation plugin and and use regex to validate one field. Here is some code:

```
$.validator.addMethod('regex',
            function(value, element, regexp) {
            var check = false;
            var re = new RegExp(regexp);
            return this.optional(element) || re.test(value);
             },
    "" );
```

```
<input id="school" name="school" type="text" style="float: left" />
```

```
$("#school").rules("add", { regex: "^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$"});
```

But I want to use `\` and `]` symbols in this field.  Escaping these characters with backslashes doesn`t help, even with 3 or 4 backslashes as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025482/cant-escape-the-backslash-with-regex)

**Edited** 

Thanks. It was really my mistake. I updated regex to validate different symbols (also backslash and ] )

```
$("#school").rules("add", { regex: /^[a-zA-Z0-9\',!;\<>\?\$\^:\\\/`\|~&\" @#%\*\{}\(\)\[\]_\+\.\s=-]*$/ });
```

it works now.

Comment: Why `regex: "^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$"` instead of `regex: /^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/`?

Answer (score 1):

This one should work:

```js
'^[a-zA-Z0-9\\]\\\\]*$'
```

Two backlashes before ] gives one backslash in final string, and this backslash escapes ] sign.
Four backslashes produces two backslashes (two escaped backslashes) in final string, and this two backlashes passed to RegExp constructor gives one escaped backslash.

Here is simple demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CsQn7/1/