# Splitting String using split method

Tags: java, android, string, parsing, split

I want split a string like this:

```
  C:\Program\files\images\flower.jpg
```

but, using the following code:

```
  String[] tokens = s.split("\\");
  String image= tokens[4];
```

I obtain this error:

```
 11-07 12:47:35.960: E/AndroidRuntime(6921): java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Syntax error U_REGEX_BAD_ESCAPE_SEQUENCE near index 1:
```

Comment: But I want split the Original String in 5 parts:

C:
Program
files
images
flower.jpg

Comment: @Joseph82 whatever Esailija is saying will work for you

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025482/cant-escape-the-backslash-with-regex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try

```
String s="C:\\Program\\files\\images\\flower.jpg"

String[] tokens = s.split("\\\\");
```

In java(regex world) `\` is a meta character. you should append with an extra \ or enclose it with \Q\E if you want to treat a meta character as a normal character.

below are some of the metacharacters

```
<([{\^-=$!|]})?*+.>
```

to treat any of the above listed characters as  normal characters you either have to escape them with '\' or enclose them around \Q\E

like:

```
        \\\\ or \\Q\\\\E
```

Comment: @Joseph82, the reason it works is because a Regex pattern starts and ends with the \ sign, and you need to escape the special char \ so you start and end the pattern with the \ sign, and then the pattern itself is the special char (with escaping) \\. all in all it's \\\\

Answer (score 2):

You need to split with `\\\\`, because the original string should have `\\`. Try it yourself with the following test case:

```
    @Test
public void split(){
      String s = "C:\\Program\\files\\images\\flower.jpg";     


        String[] tokens = s.split("\\\\");
        String image= tokens[4];
        assertEquals("flower.jpg",image);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is 2 levels of interpreting the string, first the language parser makes it `"\"`, and that's what the regex engine sees and it's invalid because it's an escape sequence without the character to escape.

So you need to use `s.split("\\\\")`, so that the regex engine sees `\\`, which in turn means a literal `\`.

If you are defining that string in a string literal, you must escape the backslashes there as well:

```
String s = "C:\\Program\\files\\images\\flower.jpg";
```

Answer (score 1):

String[] tokens=s.split("\\\\");

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String s = "C:/Program/files/images/flower.jpg";
String[] tokens = s.split("/");
enter code hereString image= tokens[4];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your original input text should be

```
 C:\\Program\\files\\images\\flower.jpg
```

instead of

```
 C:\Program\files\images\flower.jpg
```

Comment: I get the String from a web service. So I insert the path in the string in this way (using Ksoap2):

s = response.getProperty("image").toString();

Answer (score 0):

This works,

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "C:\\Program\\files\\images\\flower.jpg";
        str = str.replace("\\".toCharArray()[0], "/".toCharArray()[0]);
        System.out.println(str);
        String[] tokens  = str.split("/");
        System.out.println(tokens[4]);      
    }
```