# Print a string with unformatted characters ("\t" instead of a tab)

Tags: java, regex

I am reading a string of text from a source that I cannot see otherwise. I would like to see the actual formatting codes such as: `\t \n` etc. instead of actual tabs and newline

When I print the String using `System.out.println`, I see the tabs visually and would have to count them by highlight with the mouse.

I've tried using a regex to replace the `\t` in the string with a `\\t` but I have little experience with regex so I'm not sure if my expression is correct. Here's what I have:

```
String text = extractor.getText();
text.replaceAll("\n", "\\n");
```

**I would appreciate an alternate method of doing this without regex if possible.** I'm using an `XSSFExcelExtractor` if it makes any difference.

Comment: I realize that the formatting codes like '\n' are a single character. I'm guessing I can't match just the \

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using StringEscapeUtils from apache commons if you want to see all characters that Java will convert

```
String s="\r\t\n abc";
System.out.println(StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(s));
```

output

```
\r\t\n abc
```

---

In case you want to escape only `\t` or `\n` you can use

```
String escaped = origina.replace("\t","\\t").replace("\n","\\n)"`
```

Comment: I like this, it's only for testing so I don't mind using apache commons. Still it would be nice to find a simpler way to do this. I'm going to leave the question open to see if someone suggests a built-in technique

Comment: Yeah that works, I saw CharSequence and for some reason thought it wouldn't accept a plain string, should have used `replace()` instead of `replaceAll()`. Secondly. if `escapeJava(String)` had to be built into commons I'll assume there's no duplicated functionality in the Java API, making your answer as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
String s="\r\t\n abc";
System.out.println(StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(s));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
text.replaceAll("\\\", "/");
```

Comment: This throws a java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException. I belive that a single backslash is found with the regex "\\\\"  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025482/cant-escape-the-backslash-with-regex/4025505#4025505

Comment: If it is a suggestion, please leave it in the comments section. If you are really answering, please follow SO formatting.