# Finding and replacing file path within string doesn't work in actionscript 3

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, replace, find

I need to replace the source of some `<img>` in a HTML formatted string, but after I extract the URLs they don't match with the original string. This simple code should work, but it doesn't:

```
var str1:String = "<img src=\"file:///D:\\boo\\hoo\\hoo\\pic.jpg\">";
var str2:String = "file:///D:\\boo\\hoo\\hoo\\pic.jpg";
var i:int = str1.search(str2);
```

There is no match with `src1.split(src2)` either. I must be doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what.

Comment: Try escaping the backslashes further: `file:///D:\\\\boo\\\\hoo\\\\hoo\\\\pic.jpg`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Jerry is right.

The pattern try to search the string with double backslash, you need 4 backslash.

You can read a explanation [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025482/cant-escape-the-backslash-with-regex).