# Escaping backslashes to indicate a newline

Tags: java, regex

If I want to search for a newline in a text using Java, should my regex be `"\n"` or `"\\n"`, or will either work?

Comment: And you didn't find answer of this question by searching?

Comment: try them both on small text passage with newline and you will find out which one works.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't escape the backslash with regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025482/cant-escape-the-backslash-with-regex)

Comment: Can you try this yourself?  Then post the answer so that we'll all know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't matching a backslahs (`\`) and an `n`, you're matching a newline character (represented as `\n`). There's no need to escape the backslash:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*\n.*");
```

Comment: It shouldn't be `.*\n` only ? If not, what are you matching after the new line ?