# preg_match() with backslashes doesn't work as expected / throws error

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match

I need to `preg_match()` a pattern in PHP and no matter what I do I get errors.

I've looked all over the net and can't find anything that tells me what I'm actually doing wrong.

Here's my `preg_match` pattern:

```
preg_match('/\MyApp\Library\Task\/', '\MyApp\Library\Task\Db\Generate');
```

It always returns an array, what do I do wrong? How can I get my regex to work properly?

Comment: Shouldn't you escape the backslashes in your regular expression ? This problem has been mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025482/cant-escape-the-backslash-with-regex :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I know it will sound crazy, but you need to use 4 backslashes to get 1 backslash for your regex. So your code would look something like this:

```
preg_match('/\\\\MyApp\\\\Library\\\\Task\\\\/', '\MyApp\Library\Task\Db\Generate');
```

Why do you need to use 4? Because in PHP you use a backslash to escape the following character, so you escape it to get one literal backslash (`\\`).

But since we are are in a regular expression you need to escape a backslash if you want a backslash in your regex, means you have to use `\\` two backslashes which with PHP end up in one to escape the other two backslashes which always end up in one character, which then end up as a single backslash in your regex.