# want to replace \ in pig latin using replace command

Tags: apache-pig

I have a file having data like below in pig

```
<"{\"action\": \"ac_data\",\"data\":{\"nn1\":\"0000000\",\"zerosquare\":\"newuser\",\"nacde\":\"catlogue\",\"user123\":\"99000200340904\",\"lcadq\":\"89148000001972298094\",\"reserve\":\
```

And I want to remove \ and the output should be  as below

```
<"{"action": "ac_data","data":{"nn1":"0000000","zerosquare":"newuser","nacde":"catlogue","user123":"99000200340904","lcadq":"89148000001972298094","reserve":
```

Answer (score 0):

**Input :**

```
<"{\"action\": \"ac_data\",\"data\":{\"nn1\":\"0000000\",\"zerosquare\":\"newuser\",\"nacde\":\"catlogue\",\"user123\":\"99000200340904\",\"lcadq\":\"89148000001972298094\",\"reserve\":\
```

**Pig Script :**

```
A = LOAD 'input.csv' as line;  
B = FOREACH A GENERATE REPLACE(line,'([\\\\]+)','');  
dump B;
```

**Output :**

```
(<"{"action": "ac_data","data":{"nn1":"0000000","zerosquare":"newuser","nacde":"catlogue","user123":"99000200340904","lcadq":"89148000001972298094","reserve":)
```

**Ref :**

[Can't escape the backslash with regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025482/cant-escape-the-backslash-with-regex)