# How to split a tuple in character '\' in PIG

Tags: apache-pig, strsplit

I'm beginning learn PIG and I  want to split a tuple in character '\'.
My original tuple is

```
(192.168.2.227\al0000)
```

and I need to split it in '\'

```
(192.168.2.227, al0000)
```

I tryed to use

```
B =  FOREACH original GENERATE FLATTEN (STRSPLIT(tuple, '\\u034B'));
```

but it dont work. What is the proper solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Input :**

```
192.168.2.227\al0000
```

**Pig Script :**

```
A = LOAD 'input.csv' as line;  
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN (STRSPLIT(line, '([\\\\])'));
dump B;
```

Second argument used is a regex to identify '\'

**Output :**

```
(192.168.2.227,al0000)
```

**Ref** :

1. http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/func.html#strsplit
2. [Can't escape the backslash with regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025482/cant-escape-the-backslash-with-regex)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `'\\\\'` in place of the strange unicode code point u034B?

Comment: Yes , I tried, but the PIG shows a ">>" and waits for some input

Comment: Hm, strange, the docs say it is a wrapper for Java String split() method.
Maybe just two backslashes (e.g. '\\')?
Also, it might be that you do not have a "tuple".
What is before this in your script?