# How to replace 'n' back slashes (\) with one?

Tags: java, regex, replace

I would like to squeeze out 'n' number of slashes into 1, where n is not fixed.

For example:

```
String path = "Report\\\\\\n";
```

Expected output : `"Report\\n"`

I tried the following way

```
System.out.println(path.replaceAll("\\+", "\");
```

But it's printing `"Report\\\n"`

I am not able to reduce more than that.

All the related so question/answer related to fixed number of slashes.

Is there any generic way I can squeeze all backslashes to one?

Comment: Check out [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025482/cant-escape-the-backslash-with-regex) for a good explanation of backslash escaping.

Comment: According to [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String) ) you should avoid replacing with single `backslash` using `String.replaceAll()`. It's recomended to use `Matcher`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you print `path`, you'll get:

```
Report\\\n
```

That's because `\` should be quoted and it's written as `\\` in Java.

You should do:

```
System.out.println(path.replaceAll("\\\\+", "\\\\"));
```

#### Explanation:

In (pure) regex, in order to match the *literal* `\`, you should quote it. So it's represented as:

```
\\
```

In Java, `\` is represented as `\\`, simple math should explain the 4 `\`s.

Comment: @Codebender Because `"\"` won't work as the compiler will think you quoted the `"`. You need to double-quote it.

Comment: You are right. Looks the 2nd argument should be regex compatible too. Didn't know that.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Could you please explain the logic?

Comment: @nantitv in 30 mins I'll arrive home ans will explain my answer.

Comment: @MarounMaroun I understood it.  This have a nice explanation for it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025482/cant-escape-the-backslash-with-regex

Comment: @nantitv It's indeed good explanation. I added mine to make the answer complete. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape. A lot.

```
System.out.println("Report\\\\\\n");
System.out.println("Report\\\\\\n".replaceAll("[\\\\]+", "\\\\"));
```

Prints out:

```
Report\\\n
Report\n
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two method indexOf() and lastIndexOf() to get actual start and end index of string '\\....'
Then simply get substring using substring method.

Answer (score 0):

You just need the first and the last position of the "\" inside the String. Then create a String without the info between those positions.

```
int firstIndex = path.indexOf("\\");
int lastIndex = path.lastIndexOf("\\");
String result = path.substring(0, firstIndex) + path.substring(lastIndex, path.length());
```

Answer (score -1):

For replacing multiple forward slashes with a single forward slash you could use:

```
.replaceAll("(?)[//]+", "/");
```

For replacing multiple backward slashes with a single backward slash you could use:

```
.replaceAll("(?)[\\\\]+", "\\\\");
```

Comment: Why is my post -1, I tried my code out and it works. (Also i was one of the first to post... :-S) Can the one who downvoted my post at least give an explenation why it would be a negative answer.