# Include backslash in regular expression for URL sanitize?

Tags: php, regex, url

I have the following regular expression:

```
$url = "http://example.com?param=test1\test2\test3\test4";

$cleanUrl = preg_replace('|[^a-z0-9-~+_.?\[\]\^#=!&;,/:%@$\|*`\'<>"()\\x80-\\xff\{\}]|i', '', $url);
```

I get the following output:

> http://example.com?param=test1est2est3est4

But,
I'm expecting the following output:

> http://example.com?param=test1\test2\test3\test4

I tried to this regex, but it's not working:

```
    $cleanUrl = preg_replace('|[^a-z0-9-~+_.?\[\]\^\\#=!&;,/:%@$\|*`\'<>"()\\x80-\\xff\{\}]|i', '', $url);
                                                    ^ escaped single quote
```

Comment: Are you sure about the input string? See https://ideone.com/OnepGA. I think it should be `$url = "http://example.com?param=test1\\test2\\test3\\test4";`. Then use `$cleanUrl = preg_replace('|[^-\\\\a-z0-9~+_.?\[\]\^#=!&;,/:%@$\|*\`\'<>"()\x80-\xff\{\}]|i', '', $url);`. See [this demo](https://ideone.com/tUHtU3).

Comment: You have to use \\\\ to escape a backslash. Read this [SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4025505/5447994)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, what you are doing can be achieved with other means, but answering your question, I should note that your input string does not contain backslashes, it contains *tab* characters as inside double quoted string literal, `\t` defines an escape sequence.

Once you use a single quoted literal, `\t` denotes 2 symbols. Now, the regex does not have `\`. You need to add it with `\\\\`:

```
$url = 'http://example.com?param=test1\test2\test3\test4';
$cleanUrl = preg_replace('|[^-\\\\a-z0-9~+_.?\[\]^#=!&;,/:%@$\|*`\'<>"()\x80-\xff{}]|i', '', $url);
echo $cleanUrl;
```

See [this PHP demo](https://ideone.com/hatRUC) printing `http://example.com?param=test1\test2\test3\test4`.

I also moved the `-` to the beginning (it is just best practice to put it at the start or end of the character class if it should match a literal hyphen), and `^` that is not in the initial position in the char class does not have to be escaped. Same goes for `{`, `}`, and also `[`, but that square bracket is better escaped (some regex flavors disallow unescaped `[` in the character class).