# Python string pattern match not work

Tags: python, regex

In this python string pattern matching, I want to filter out s1, it should be like *\2017-01-23\ , date string followed by a '\' . Any idea?

```
s1="historyData\xx\n3_1010366372_2017-01-25_1126807";
s2="historyData\xx\2017-01-23\n3_1010366372_2017-01-25_1126807";
date_reg_exp = re.compile('\d{4}[-/]\d{2}[-/]\d{2}\\');

 mat = re.match(date_reg_exp, s)
      if mat is not None:
        print("not matched")
      else:
        print("matched")
```

Comment: So in the first string there will be no date match right?

Comment: Is this purely down to you using `re.match` instead of `re.search`? The former only matching the beginning of a string (as if there was an implicit `^` at the start of the pattern)

Comment: python doesn't use semicolons.

Comment: Probably related t http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025482/cant-escape-the-backslash-with-regex (as well as match v search)

Comment: Also you will most likely need to escape the \ characters in your strings to avoid invalid escape sequence errors

Comment: @user1615666 please check the answers. Accepting one if it helps would help search  point to right answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `search` instead of `match`

Here is what [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match) says

> Python offers two different primitive operations based on regular
>   expressions: re.match() checks for a match only at the beginning of
>   the string, while re.search() checks for a match anywhere in the
>   string (this is what Perl does by default).

The strings provided had invalid `\x` escape .To use them as row string you may use r"string" .The `s1` and `s2` variables be written as

```
s1=r"historyData\xx\n3_1010366372_2017-01-25_1126807"
s2=r"historyData\xx\2017-01-23\n3_1010366372_2017-01-25_1126807"
```

You may re-write the function as follows.

```
 import re
 def containsDate(s):
        date_reg_exp = re.compile(r'(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})')
        mat = re.search(date_reg_exp,s)
        return mat is not None
```

Now the functions may be used as follows

```
s1=r"historyData\xx\n3_1010366372_2017-01-25_1126807"
s2=r"historyData\xx\2017-01-23\n3_1010366372_2017-01-25_1126807"

if containsDate(s1):
    print "match"
else:
    print "no match"
```

Comment: thanks, but I don't want to extract date, just match or not match

Comment: @user1615666 returning None would be the not match scenario

Comment: @user1615666 updated the answer by the way you can do the None check in the `getDate` function itself and return `match` or `nomatch`

Comment: can you modify your script ? almost there.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use a raw string instead of string. Because `\xx` is not a recognized character.

`a = "\xx"` will throw `ValueError: invalid \x escape`

You can try like so:

```
import re

s1 = r"historyData\xx\n3_1010366372_2017-01-25_1126807"
s2 = r"historyData\xx\2017-01-23\n3_1010366372_2017-01-25_1126807"

s = r"(?:.*?\\)(\d+-\d+-\d+)(?:\\.*)$"
reg = re.compile(s)

print re.match(reg, s1)
print re.match(reg, s2).group(1)
```

Output:

```
None
2017-01-23
```