# preg_match_all(): Compilation failed: missing )

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter

I don't know where i'm making mistake. Please Help.

```
   preg_match_all('`(?:[^,"]|"((?<=\)"|[^"])*")*`x', $string, $result);
```

What will be the correct line?

Comment: You have escaped `)` in `(?<=\)`, so unmatching close brace

Comment: I tried to escape it by adding backslash but it didn't helped.

Comment: To escape backslash, you should use \\\\ not just \\. This [SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4025505/5447994) might help

Comment: ok. I just tried and it worked. Thanks

Comment: 3 backslash worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You did not escape the backslash:

```
preg_match_all('`(?:[^,"]|"((?<=\\)"|[^"])*")*`x', $string, $result);
```

Or, if you don't intend to match a backslash at all, you then have to omit it completely:

```
preg_match_all('`(?:[^,"]|"((?<=)"|[^"])*")*`x', $string, $result);
```

Comment: I tried to do the first line means adding a backslash but it didn't helped although second line did helped. Thanks