# regular expression for double slash in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am quite new to regular expression and I want that in my regular expression it should accept only `\\` (double back slash ) and not `\` (single back slash).

```
         isFilePathValid: function (get) {
           var forbiddenCharactersRegexp = /[<>|?*]/,
               directorySeparatorsRegexp = /[/\\]/,
              directorySeparatorsRegexp1 = /[\\{2}]/,
              filePath = get('filePath').trim();

        return directorySeparatorsRegexp.test(filePath)
            && 
       !directorySeparatorsRegexp.test(filePath.charAt(filePath.length - 1))
            && !forbiddenCharactersRegexp.test(filePath) && 
        directorySeparatorsRegexp1.test(filePath) ;
    }
```

the correct file paths are 
1. \\abc
2. C:\abd
3. C:\abd\abc

Comment: Could you be more specific on this? Should the regex accept *only* two backslashes? Should it accept the backslashes amongst other characters or just on their own? Should it accept more than just 1 pair of backslashes or just the one? Provide example test cases, highlighting what would pass and what wouldn't.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure you have two occurences using `{2}`, this is the Regex you need:

```
/\\{2}/g
```

This is a [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8R3gyW/1).

**Edit:**

Make sure you escape the `\` as `\\` in your string because the string parser in your program will remove one of them when "de-escaping" it for the string, you can check [the discussion her](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4025505/3669624) and that's why it didn't work in your case.

This is a Demo snippet:

```js
const regex = /\\{2}/g;
const str = `A sample text \\\\ that has nothing\\ on it.`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }

  // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
  m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
    console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
  });
}
```

Note the escaped `\\\\` in the Demo string.

Comment: this is my code                                                                                                         isFilePathValid: function (get) {
            var forbiddenCharactersRegexp = /[<>|?*]/,
                directorySeparatorsRegexp = /[/\\]/,
                filePath = get('filePath').trim();

            return directorySeparatorsRegexp.test(filePath)
                && !directorySeparatorsRegexp.test(filePath.charAt(filePath.length - 1))
                && !forbiddenCharactersRegexp.test(filePath);
        }

Answer (score 0):

Try with following regular exprsssion

```
^^(\\\\){1}$
```

Comment: this will accept \\, \\\\, and any other multiple of 2

Comment: You need only double

Comment: try this `^(\\\\){1}$`