# Replace backslash in a string using regex

Tags: javascript

Why does this works:

```
'ye+low'.replace(/\+/g, 'l')
// > yellow
```

but this does NOT work:

```
'ye\low'.replace(/\\/g, 'l')
// > yelow
```

??

I need to replace ONE backslash with something, but I can't seem to make it happen.

NOTE: I CAN'T change the string as it comes in a variable.

**EDIT**: I understand `\` is an escape character in javascript. This is fine with my understanding and I read plenty of other SO answers in this regard. My question is: "Ok I know, but still: HOW DO I REPLACE `ye\low` to be `yellow` using javascript?" I understand regex may not be the way to go because of its interpretation of backslashes, but I bet there is some way to get the desired output i some fashion.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025482/cant-escape-the-backslash-with-regex

Comment: Sorry it is not relevant. It just explains why backslashes are treated differently. I need a way to turn `ye\low` to `yellow`.

Comment: `'ye\low'` does not contain any blackslash. Use console.log('ye\low') to confirm this. `'ye\low'` is not valid and is then converted to just `'yelow'` without the slash. See my answer below for explanation to why.

Comment: @JonaRodrigues I think it might help if you put this into context. Is it only the word `ye\low` literally your only concern? Is it a limited group of words instead? Where is this data from?

Comment: @zer00ne Actually this a bit off context: the `ye\low` string is actually a RegEx that someone gives me. With this RegEx, I am supposed to create a `new RegExp(userRegex, 'g')`. Now after several readings, I found that `userRegex` should be escaped in order to be correctly turned into a regex object. So I am now fighting to escape the escape character `\\`. I thought I was doing a good job by narrowing down the problem to a shorter problem, but it seems to cause more confusion...

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't go to the end user and tell him "please double each of your backslashes for me"... As I understand they use their regex for other purposes and their job is not toward modifying regexes manually (neither does mine...) This is why, I try to find a way to escape `\\` using javascript and not me doing the job by hand.

Comment: @JonaRodrigues Ah, then I think I know what you need to overcome this escaping issue. See my answer.

Comment: If you want to represent a backslash in code, you have to escape the backslash like this `'ye\\low'`. This might look like two backslashes, but this is the code that represents ONE backslash.

Comment: Please see the demo provided in my answer to better demonstrate how to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

You code shows `\l`, which is not 2 characters, but one character. It is an invalid escape code that falls back to just `l`. If you want to represent a backslash in code, you have to escape the backslash like this `'ye\\low'`. This might look like two backslashes, but this is the code that represents ONE backslash.

This is a string of 5 characters: `'ye\low'`.

```
console.log('ye\low')
// "yelow"

'ye\low'.length === 5
```

These two blocks of code are identical:

```
'ye\low'.replace(/\\/g, 'l')
'yelow'.replace(/\\/g, 'l')
```

The character `\l` is invalid and is translated to an `l` with no slash.

If your string has a slash in it, you have to escape the backslash like this: `'yel\\low'`

```
const yelloWith_ONE_Backslash = 'ye\\low'

console.log(yelloWith_ONE_Backslash)
// "ye\low"

'ye\\low'.length === 6
// true

console.log('yelow')
// "yelow"

console.log('ye\low')
// "yelow"

console.log('ye\\low')
// "ye\low"

console.log('ye\\\\low')
// "ye\\low"
```

So you would do this:

`'ye\\low'.replace(/\\/g, 'l')`

### Demo

```js
var input = prompt('Try to type `ye\\low`')
var replaced = input.replace(/\\/g, 'l')

alert(replaced)
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. But I don't have access to the variable... I can't replace it manually before computing the `replace()` function: that's actually why I use the replace function. If I could modify it manually, I would change it to 'yellow' directly... ahah

Comment: You would not be doing a replace. `var yelow = 'ye\\low' // > yel\low`. Try to output  `'ye\\low'` and you will see there is only 1 slash in the actual string, even though the code will contain 2.

Comment: `'ye\low'` is not valid. The value can only be either `'yelow'` or `'ye\\low'`. You can check this by running `'ye\low' === 'yelow' // true`. `.replace(/\\/g, 'l')` will work. It's your test code (`'ye\low'`) that is wrong.

Comment: thanks for your lights. Anyway, I unfortunately have this misleading `ye\low` string to be changed to `yellow`... I don't know what to do about that, there should be some hack to replace that using a computer and some instructions, right ?

Comment: I have updated my answer to help. The value `'\\'` represents a single character that is a blackslash. What you are suggesting not possible. `.replace(/\\/g, 'l')` will work for you.

Comment: Open up your developer console and type this into it `'ye\low'`. You will see the value of that is `'yelow'`. If you are looking for a value of `'ye\low'`, the JavaScript you must write will be `'ye\\low'`.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. The point is `ye\low` comes from a user input. I can't instruct him to double its backslashes because I can't program it. So what would be the best way to tell javscript that for this string, the `\\` should not be an escape character ?

Comment: Another way to see the problem would be: how would I make `ye\low` to be `ye\\low` then ?

Comment: When the user enters his input as `ye\low` and we set it to `myVar` you would test it with `myVar === 'ye\\low' // > true`. Please re-read and test the code I have suggested.

Comment: You can confirm this by entering this into your browsers console `alert(prompt().replace(/\\/g, 'l'))`. When prompted, enter the value `ye\low`.

Comment: If the user enters the value `ye\\low`, you would test that with `input === 'ye\\\\low'` `\\` is one single backslash.

Comment: Sorry, this does not fit my needs. I just have this string with ONE backslash stuffed in it. I am not the proprietary of the input-side code... I just get `ye\low` and need to convert it to `yellow`. Nothing less, nothing more.

Comment: This absolutely does fit your needs. THIS IS THE ANSWER! `'ye\low'` contains ZERO backslashes. `'ye\\low'` contains ONE backslash. You can confirm this by entering this into your browsers console `alert(prompt().replace(/\\/g, 'l'))`. When prompted, enter the value `ye\low`

Comment: Sorry but read the question and description... I CANNOT MODIFY `ye\low` to `ye\\low` manually. If your answer involves modifying the original `ye\low` string, then you are not replying to my question. I don't mean to be rude or what, I appreciate your explanations sincerely and you helped me find the correct answer. Now, I can't upvote an answer telling me to change something I explicitly told I don't have hands over... Sorry. My own amswer does the trick, as it allows me to replace `ye\low` WITHOUT doing it manually, but using javascript instead.

Comment: Okay, let's back up a bit. How is this JavaScript file being created? How is the user input being received? I believe there is a key element being left out of this problem. Is the user input assigned to a variable? something similar to this `var input = prompt('enter text')`? Can you please post more of your code because `'ye\low'` is not a valid string literal in JavaScript. That becomes translated to `'yelow'`. So there is never a slash in the literal.

Answer (score 0):

I found this to work for me:

```
// This allows backslash to be ineffective, meaning ye\low will remain as a string with 6 characters INCLUDING the \
var value = String.raw`ye\low`;
console.log( value.replace('/\\/g', 'l') )
```

Output is

> yellow

To use with caution as it is not widely supported by all browsers yet. See more here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw

Comment: `String.raw\`ye\low\` === 'ye\\low'`. These two are *triple equals identical*. `'ye\\low'` contains only ONE backslash. Please re-read my original answer to understand why. `if (String.raw\`ye\low\` === 'ye\\low') { console.log('ALWAYS TRUE!'); }`

Comment: I have modified my answer to include a demo to PROVE to you this is the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks @joelnet. Like I said, you are right: but you are not replying to the original question which states: `NOTE: I CAN'T change the string as it comes in a variable.` which means what it means: I can't put my mouse between `ye` and `\low` and add something here. I just can't... So I need a solution that STARTS with the string `ye\low`. If any solution involves touching the `ye\low` string by other means than javascript... then the answer is out of scope. Using `String.raw` I leave the original string/sequence untouched and the `replace()` finally matches the `\\`.

Comment: Can you please post more of your code? I would like to see what you mean by "it comes in a variable". Specifically, I am looking for how the user's input gets assigned to the variable. Because the Demo I provided gets the user's input, assigns it to a variable and then replaces the slash with an l. Did you run the Demo in my example?